# Why does QGIS crash when extracting pixel values by GDAL?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, pixel

In below code I want to print pixel values, but when run in QGIS python console QGIS software crashes and closed! what is the problem?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy
import struct

def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
    return QgsPoint(xp, yp)

# Open tif file
ds = QgsRasterLayer("/Data/Sample_Polygon.tif","Study")

pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

# extent of the Raster layer
ext = ds.extent()

originX ,originY = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
src_cols = ds.width()
src_rows = ds.height()
drive = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' )
src_ds = gdal.Open("/Data/Sample_Polygon.tif")
outBand = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

outData = numpy.zeros((src_cols, src_rows), numpy.float32)

pntRstList = []

for i in range(0, src_cols):
    for j in range(0, src_rows):
        rspnt = pixel2coord(i,j)
        pntRstList.append(rspnt)

for x, y in pntRstList:
    structval=outBand.ReadRaster(x,y,1,1,buf_type=gdal.GDT_Float32)
    intval = struct.unpack('f' , structval)
    val=intval[0]
    print val
```

Also I test the @xunilk code in [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137759/extract-raster-values-gdal-looping-rasters/137797#137797), and closed the QGIS software again. I use QGIS 2.18.9 in Linux Mint 18.

Comment: 'ReadRaster' GDAL method has a very different syntax that you used for unpacking data with struct. That's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is because 'ReadRaster' GDAL method has a very different syntax that you used for unpacking data with struct. Furthermore, you need 'BandType' to determine adequate 'fmttype' to be used in unpacking (see dictionary in last lines in next code). I change your paths to adequate to my example raster (20 x 20).

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy
import struct

def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
    return QgsPoint(xp, yp)

# Open tif file
ds = QgsRasterLayer("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio1.tif","Study")

pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

# extent of the Raster layer
ext = ds.extent()

originX ,originY = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
src_cols = ds.width()
src_rows = ds.height()
drive = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' )
src_ds = gdal.Open("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio1.tif")
outBand = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

outData = numpy.zeros((src_cols, src_rows), numpy.float32)

pntRstList = []

for i in range(0, src_cols):
    for j in range(0, src_rows):
        rspnt = pixel2coord(i,j)
        pntRstList.append(rspnt)

fmttypes = {'Byte':'B', 'UInt16':'H', 'Int16':'h', 'UInt32':'I', 'Int32':'i', 'Float32':'f', 'Float64':'d'}
BandType = gdal.GetDataTypeName(outBand.DataType)

for y in range(outBand.YSize):
    scanline = outBand.ReadRaster(0, y, outBand.XSize, 1, outBand.YSize, 1, outBand.DataType)
    values = struct.unpack(fmttypes[BandType] * outBand.YSize, scanline)
    print values
```

After running it at Python Console of QGIS, I didn't have any error. This was result (20 tuples of 20 values):

```
(1, 6, 4, 9, 4, 7, 3, 2, 7, 9, 4, 8, 5, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 9, 6)
(10, 8, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 8, 8, 1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 1)
(4, 5, 6, 9, 5, 4, 1, 10, 1, 4, 9, 8, 10, 6, 1, 9, 5, 7, 9, 7)
(3, 8, 5, 3, 2, 3, 10, 3, 7, 2, 3, 8, 3, 7, 7, 7, 10, 6, 5, 3)
(7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 3, 7, 7, 5, 10, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 10, 2, 5, 4)
(7, 9, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 9, 8, 4, 5, 9, 8, 1, 4, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6)
(5, 4, 1, 8, 2, 4, 7, 4, 10, 9, 3, 8, 8, 3, 2, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6)
(7, 8, 8, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4, 10, 6, 5)
(3, 9, 6, 9, 10, 1, 9, 5, 1, 3, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 9)
(1, 8, 9, 6, 2, 9, 8, 5, 10, 5, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2, 8, 4)
(3, 6, 10, 3, 2, 9, 10, 6, 7, 7, 8, 3, 7, 7, 1, 5, 8, 1, 4, 9)
(10, 8, 6, 8, 6, 4, 8, 4, 3, 2, 10, 2, 10, 3, 1, 4, 9, 1, 2, 8)
(7, 4, 9, 2, 2, 10, 9, 10, 7, 4, 3, 3, 10, 4, 6, 6, 7, 3, 1, 7)
(4, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 10, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 6, 4, 3, 8, 5)
(3, 5, 9, 4, 2, 4, 8, 8, 7, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 10, 7, 6, 3, 7, 3)
(2, 4, 8, 1, 10, 5, 2, 10, 7, 9, 7, 8, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 10, 2, 9)
(7, 5, 2, 9, 1, 1, 2, 8, 10, 10, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 10, 9)
(7, 4, 10, 4, 2, 6, 1, 10, 7, 4, 9, 3, 4, 10, 1, 9, 3, 4, 9, 8)
(9, 10, 1, 10, 9, 10, 4, 6, 10, 2, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 4, 9, 8)
(3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 10, 5, 2, 1, 7, 3, 10, 6, 6, 1, 1, 10, 6, 6)
```

Comment: Hi @xunilk, Thanks for your help. I used your code but unfortunately QGIS crashed again. Can I asked what is your version of QGIS and  OS?

Comment: It could be your raster. Try with my 20x20 raster first. I will hang it in dropbox. Please, wait a moment. By the way, my QGIS is 2.18.10 and I use a Debian stable system.

Comment: It's another raster but it is also 20 x20: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0el8ewzpf7rwjzd/aleatorio.tif?dl=0

Comment: Sorry @xunilk, I used your raster file but It crashed again.